# Subir imagen a SQL Server con PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Buen día.

Tengo un problema, hay un sistema realizado que trabaja con SQl Server donde tiene varias tablas dentro, hay una que contiene fotos y la firma del personal, el detalle es el siguiente:

El sistema esta realizado en C# sin embargo no existe el código fuente para poder modificarlo y el detalle que se requiere es que la foto de firma se remplace por un código QR.

Ya se cuenta con el sistema en PHP listando al Personal con la función de poder generar el QR, sin embargo a la hora de querer guardar el QR, no es posible guardarlo. el formato binario que estoy mandando no me acepta para poder mostrar el Qr. Espero y puedan ayudarme.

[image: Listado del personal mostrando su firma:]

[image: Forma de subir el Qr]

Esa seria la forma de manera grafica de como subo el QR.

Ahora este es mi código del cual subo el QR.

```
 <form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'" method="POST" name="qr" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id_empl" value="'.$row["id_emp"].'">
                                    <input type="file" name="foto" accept="" multiple>
                                    <br>
                                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="qr.submit">Guardar cambios
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
```

//

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 
    
    $errores = '';
    //Hacemos condición para que sea necesario el ID
    
    if(isset($_POST['id_empl'])){
        $id_empl = $_POST['id_empl'];

        $foto_name= $_FILES["foto"]["name"];
        $foto_size= $_FILES["foto"]["size"];
        $foto_type= $_FILES["foto"]["type"];

        $foto_temporal= $_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"];
        
        if ($foto_type=="image/x-png" OR $foto_type=="image/png"){
            $extension="image/png";
        }if ($foto_type=="image/pjpeg" OR $foto_type=="image/jpeg"){
            $extension="image/jpeg";
        }if ($foto_type=="image/gif" OR $foto_type=="image/gif"){
            $extension="image/gif";
        }

        /*Reconversion de la imagen para meter en la tabla abrimos el fichero temporal en modo lectura "r" y binaria "b"*/
        $f1= fopen($foto_temporal,'rb');
    
        # Leemos el fichero completo limitando la lectura al tamaño del fichero
                $foto_reconvertida = fread($f1, $foto_size);
        
        /* Anteponemos "\" a las comillas que pudiera contener el fichero para evitar que sean interpretadas como final de cadena.*/
            $foto_reconvertida = base64_encode($foto_reconvertida);
        
        //cerrar el fichero temporal
        fclose($f1);
        
        
   
        //Hacemos condición para Actualizar el Registro
       if (empty($id_empl)){
                $errores .= '<p>* Ocurrio un Error, vuelve a intentarlo</p>';
            }else{
                $actualizarQr = "UPDATE reg_fotfir SET img_firma = '$foto_reconvertida' WHERE exp_empleado = '$id_empl'";
                sqlsrv_query($conn, $actualizarQr);

                $actualizarFecha = "UPDATE datos_emp SET update_at = '$fechaHora' WHERE id_emp = '$id_empl'";
                sqlsrv_query($conn, $actualizarFecha); 

                header('Location: listado?estado=good');
            } 
}
```

}

Ahora una vez que lo subo me arroja este código binario.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo no me muestra la foto, y el código binario que si muestra las fotos es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se que estoy haciendo mal, espero y puedan ayudarme.

Nota: se que no es practico subir las imágenes a la BD, sin embargo el sistema donde tiene toda esa información ya no se cuenta con el código para poder modificarlo.

Comment: ¿Por qué no solo guardar los datos necesarios para generar el código QR cada vez que sea necesario?

Comment: El detalle es que se requiere guardar la imagen QR, ya que el sistema que esta desarrollado en C# es para la impresión de Credenciales.

Comment: ¿Por qué guardarías la imagen en una `bd`? Lo recomendable sería que guardes la imagen en el servidor y almacenes la ruta en SQL

Comment: Exacto, el detalle es que el sistema ya es de años anteriores entonces así lo dejaron desarrollado, es por eso que solo existe la aplicación instalada sin embargo ya no se cuenta con el código para poder actualizarlo y jalar solo la ruta de las imágenes.

Comment: Si no tienes el código original, porque no intentas otra solución?? Agrega un campo a la tabla y haces todo lo de las firmas en ese nuevo campo, osea guardar la ruta...

Comment: De echo, fue lo primero que se realizo, sin embargo existe un sistema de **Impresión de Credenciales**, el cual toma como campo la imagen cargada de la **Base de Datos**, entonces al pasar el campo donde se encuentra la ruta, la credencial sale vacia

Comment: En SQL Server hay un tipo de dato tipo `image` puedes verle que tipo de formato tiene ese campo en la base de datos???

Comment: @SantiagoTrujilloTerán, publique la foto, para que veas el campo

Comment: Me parece que tienes una confusión base64 es distinto a binario (incluso podrían considerarse totalmente opuestos)  y tu debes guardar en binario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No codifiques a base64, parametriza el SQL y usa streams.

```
$f = fopen( $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], 'r' );
$result = sqlsrv_query( $conn
                      , "UPDATE reg_fotfir SET img_firma = ? WHERE exp_empleado = ?";
                      , [ $f
                        , $_POST['id_empl']
                        ]
                      );
fclose($f);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Sal, me ayudo mucho tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Al subir la imagen lo haces codificado a base 64(no es binario).

Al leerlo si lo hace en binario(decodificas base 64).

Asumiendo que lo haces mediante una api, para que conecte con la app que tienes, debes pasarle igualmente el valor codificado en base 64, en el codigo que tienes para leer la imagen quítale el base64_decode()

Si es al contrario( la app lee binario y no base64)
Debes cambiar el formato de "img_firma" en tu tabla
y cambiar tu codigo a que pase la imagen en formato sin procesar

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 

$errores = '';
//Hacemos condición para que sea necesario el ID

if(isset($_POST['id_empl'])){
    $id_empl = $_POST['id_empl'];

    $foto_name= $_FILES["foto"]["name"];
    $foto_size= $_FILES["foto"]["size"];
    $foto_type= $_FILES["foto"]["type"];

    $foto_temporal= $_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"];
    
    if ($foto_type=="image/x-png" OR $foto_type=="image/png"){
        $extension="image/png";
    }if ($foto_type=="image/pjpeg" OR $foto_type=="image/jpeg"){
        $extension="image/jpeg";
    }if ($foto_type=="image/gif" OR $foto_type=="image/gif"){
        $extension="image/gif";
    }

    /*Reconversion de la imagen para meter en la tabla abrimos el fichero temporal en modo lectura "r" y binaria "b"*/
    $f1= fopen($foto_temporal,'rb');

    # Leemos el fichero completo limitando la lectura al tamaño del fichero
            $foto_reconvertida = fread($f1, $foto_size);
    
    /* Anteponemos "\" a las comillas que pudiera contener el fichero para evitar que sean interpretadas como final de cadena.*/
        $foto_reconvertida = mysql_real_escape_string($foto_reconvertida);
    
    //cerrar el fichero temporal
    fclose($f1);
    
    

    //Hacemos condición para Actualizar el Registro
   if (empty($id_empl)){
            $errores .= '<p>* Ocurrio un Error, vuelve a intentarlo</p>';
        }else{
            $actualizarQr = "UPDATE reg_fotfir SET img_firma = '$foto_reconvertida' WHERE exp_empleado = '$id_empl'";
            sqlsrv_query($conn, $actualizarQr);

            $actualizarFecha = "UPDATE datos_emp SET update_at = '$fechaHora' WHERE id_emp = '$id_empl'";
            sqlsrv_query($conn, $actualizarFecha); 

            header('Location: listado?estado=good');
        }
```

}
quitandole base64_encode()

Answer (score -2):

```
$tmp_name = $files['tmp_name'];
        $name = $files['name'];
        $p = pathinfo($name);
        $extension = $p['extension'];

        if ($extension == 'pdf' or $extension == 'PDF') {
            $datai = base64_encode(file_get_contents($tmp_name));
        }
        else{
            $data = base64_encode(file_get_contents($tmp_name));

            $porciones = explode(".", $name);
            $extension = $porciones[1];
            $datai = "data:image/".$extension.";base64,".$data;
        }
```

PARA LEERLO:

```
echo "<img src='".$datai."' alt='imagenPrueba' >";
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [answer]

Comment: Disculpa, pero probe tu codigo, y no logro guardar la imagen en la BD